# What is the standard way to get/set datetime from fluid in typo3 flow?

Tags: datetime, fluid, typo3-flow

What is the standard way to get/set datetimes to/from fluid in typo3 flow?

Is there editable html field which  - like a basic f:form.textfield - will allow the datetime to be entered, edited and persisted?

I know I can display a datetime with eg 
     `<f:format.date format="d.m.Y - H:i:s">{productArticle.classdate}</f:format.date>` 
but in that case the value is null nothing gets displayed and no entry is possible anyway.  Does property work with f:format.date in some version?  I get "property not registered" when I try it.

Or do I need to have two fields on my page, one for date and one for time, that I put together in the Action?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's standard way, and personally I don't like it.. but it can be done like this:

In Fluid for new/edit actions:

```
<f:form action="create" objectName="girlfriend">
...
<f:form.textfield property="birthDate" placeholder="1991-12-30 - 18:25:58" value="{newGirlfriend.birthDate->f:format.date(format:'Y-m-d - H:i:s')}" />
...
</f:form>
```

In your controller you can add initialize*Action and update [propertyMappingConfiguration](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/PropertyMapping.html) for \DateTime if standard isn't good for you (it has to be done for both create and update action):

```
public function initializeCreateAction() {
    $mappingConfig = $this->arguments['girlfriend']->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
    $mappingConfig->forProperty('birthDate')->setTypeConverterOption(
        'TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter',
        \TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT,
        'Y-m-d - H:i:s'
    );
}
```

Sometimes it's easier to not pass object directly to controller but create it on service layer. You can also take a look at TypeConverters - they do not require initializeActions and you can easily override existing ones setting higher priority..

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure your solution is better than what I did, I just used two form fields, one for date one for time and then just put them together in the action eg ` $temporary = $this->request->getHttpRequest()->getArguments(); $datetime = $temporary['classdate'].' '.$temporary['classtime'];
   $date = new \DateTime($datetime);
   //echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); die;
   $productArticle->setClassDate($date); `

Comment: Just about getting arguments - you know that you can do sth like - createAction(ProductArticle $productArticle, $date, $time) { $dateWithTime = $date . ‘ ‘ . $time; }